# How to make a game object scale up from another game object

Tags: unity, c#, scale

I have a `GameObject`. I'm trying to make another `GameObject` grow in scale from touching `this GameObject`, and when a set amount of scale is reached, destroy `this GameObject`. My problem is that when I access `ScaleUp`, it dosn't add any scale to the other `GameObject`.

How do I scale another `GameObject`? Here is my `ScaleUp` script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScaleUp : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public GameObject Player;
    public PlayerMovement PlayerScript;

    private float playerScaleX;
    private float playerScaleY;

    public float scaleUp = 10.0f;

    void Start()
    {
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");

        PlayerScript = Player.GetComponent <PlayerMovement>();

        playerScaleX = Player.transform.localScale.x;
        playerScaleY = Player.transform.localScale.y;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player") 
        {
            playerScaleX += scaleUp;
            playerScaleY += scaleUp;

            Debug.Log ("GROW");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to actually assign a new value to `Player.transform.localScale` then, not just change the local variables `playerScaleX` and `playerScaleY`.

```
Vector3 playerScale = Player.transform.localScale;
playerScale.x += scaleUp;
playerScale.y += scaleUp;
Player.transform.localScale = playerScale;
```

or, it you really want to use the existing variables `playerScaleX` and `playerScaleY`:

```
playerScaleX += scaleUp;
playerScaleY += scaleUp;
Vector3 playerScale = Player.transform.localScale;
playerScale.x = playerScaleX;
playerScale.y = playerScaleY;
Player.transform.localScale = playerScale;
```

Comment: i want to use the scale values of the object that is going to be scaled Up and then add a certain amount of scale, the variables playerScaleX and playerScaleY are for just storing the variables of that object.                           


some like this:


player enters the trigger then his scale when inside the trigger goes up until a certain scale, at the same time the trigger  has a certain amount of scale to give, it  counts until gives it all to the player, then the trigger is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of why we *must* know the difference between a *reference* data type and a *value* data type. In this case, values are being provided *as values*. Without the actual *reference* back to your player scale, changing these values will have no effect on the original values, what so ever.

---

There are a couple of ways you could scale up another game object. *Thelo's* answer offers a solution involving a simple additional step, where you just update your new values directly back into `player.transform.scale`. You might also consider working with the `Transform` type, or passing the `Vector3` by reference.

#### Working with the automatic `Transform` reference

Classes *always* pass as reference. In this example, we have are trying to change the values of a `Vector3` in a `Transform`. If we grab a reference to the `Transform`, we can directly change the *original* `Vector3`.

```
// Note the use of SerializeField to make a private accessible to the inspector.
[SerializeField] private GameObject player;
[SerializeField] private Transform playerTransform;

// The scale increment applied by this scriptl.
public float scaleIncrement = 10f;
// The amount of scale this script has already applied.
public float appliedScale = 0f;
// The maximum scale this script can apply.
public float maxScale = 100f;

void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
    playerTransform = player.GetComponent<Transform>();
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player") 
    {
        // Apply the scale to player and add the increment to our local total.
        playerTransform.localScale += Vector3.One * scaleIncrement;
        appliedScale += scaleIncrement;

        if(appliedScale >= maxScale)
        {
            // If we have reached our max scale, destroy the local game object.
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Working with the `ref` keyword

You might find situations where you absolutely *must* use a type that would normally pass by *value*, but be able to access it as a *reference*. In these situations, [we can use the `ref` keyword in a method signature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx). It is important to note that this should be done sparingly.

In the below method, you scale a `Vector3` that is passed by reference. We will assume, in context, that it is contained in the above script. You can then call for the method with `ScaleVector(ref player.transform.localScale)`. We are now passing in `player.transform.localScale` by *reference*, so we are directly editing the *original value*.

```
void ScaleVector(ref Vector3 vector)
{
    vector += Vector3.One * scaleIncrement;
}
```

---

#### Further Reading

It is worth completing [the Unity - Data Types tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/data-types). This is a beginner tutorial, and will help you understand this problem. In C#, it is also good to remember that `struct` (e.g. `Vector2` and `Vector3`) and primitive types (e.g. `int` and `float`) automatically pass the values, while everything else (mainly `class` types) automatically pass the reference.

Answer (score -1):

Your main problem is that the object `Player.transform.localScale` is a reference value. When you change it's value, the change persists in the original place. But `Player.transform.localScale.x` and `Player.transform.localScale.y` aren't reference values. When you create a copy of those values in

```
playerScaleX
playerScaleY
```

and you modify them, `Player.transform.localScale` does not receive the modification. As a result, your game object does not scale. 
You must do something like in Thelo's sample code.

Comment: This offers a half explanation on why it is happening, but only directs users to another answer to answer the *actual* question.